# How to turn around GridView?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to display rows as columns in GridView in such a way that the first column has fields description?

Or maybe there is another control which fits to that requirement much better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Nice tutorial on Pivot tables with ADO.net can be [found here](http://aspalliance.com/538_CodeSnip_Pivot_Tables_with_ADONET_and_Display_in_a_DataGrid_Paged_Horizontally.all) to help you through the process.

Also you could build your own, using a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx). You can find an example of using the repeater [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp).

Answer (score 0):

From the DataBase itself you can change the Rows as Columns using PIVOT.
And then Bind the DataTable with the GridView.

Comment: You can use ListView instead of GridView. Have a look at this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899508/display-gridview-column-as-row